# Read 60,000 lines from excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, sql-server-2005

I have an Excel sheet that contains round about 60,000 records(lines) with 20 columns whose file size is 36mb+. when I try to read it using a file upload control in asp.net 4.0, an error comes that connection is reset. That means the file is not being read by the file upload control. Is there any way to read such a huge data.? Is there any 3rd party tool that can achieve this.?

Please help.

Comment: Can you show some code and the exact error message?

Comment: 36MB isn't very huge. Seems you have a bad network connection. If this isn't a user uploaded file, you can try out ftp

Comment: @nunespascal : I am running it no local.I have uploaded excel sheet of lines 7000 successfully. I am interested in reading the data. In another application i have uploaded 100mb data in DB in binary format. Here I am not able to read even the file.

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep : The connection was reset
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
        

        
        

  The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep : Above is the error that I am getting. I don't have permissions to attach a screen shot. So have written it in text format.

Comment: Have you debugged to confirm the upload fails? The error you mention can occur even if your application code took too long to process the 60K rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about Excel line amounts, your connection is timing out. Look into the web.config, and adjust the `executionTimeout` and `maxRequestLength` settings of the [httpRuntime Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) accordingly.

Comment: The following is my web config file.

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="600" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true"/>

Please tell me where I am going wrong. Now I am getting the error of "external table is not in the expected format"